# Share links (URLs) between iPads?

Tags: ipad, ios

Is there any easy way to share links between iPads? For example, if my friend is looking at something interesting and wants to send it to me. Is email still the best way?

Answer (score 7):

iMessage in iOS5 is a great alternative to email as you don't have to mess with a subject and it pushes the link quite rapidly to another iOS device.

Settings -> Messages -> iMessage (On)

Answer (score 3):

Device-to-Device, only e-mail, or chat software you may both be connected to would be the quickest, non-invasive way.

Comment: Since when chat is less invasive than email? O_o

Comment: I wasn't really making a claim regarding E-mail vs Chat. More E-mail/Chat < Most Other Methods. (Things like Prowl, Boxcar, etc. Externally generated notifications.)

Comment: I wish I could move the accepted answer to qthrul's. His is quite obviously much more correct as of the release of iOS 5.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea to suggest on meta. Some way to deal with orphan questions.

Comment: AirDrop, a feature built into iOS 7, running on iPad 4th generation and later can be used to easily share links between iPads.

Answer (score 1):

Email is probably the best option. Or you could use a social network site. Something like  [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com) is pretty good for stuff like that...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, e-mail. There is actually no easier way on iOS.

But I'd advise setting up something like [Yahoo Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) or [Twitter Mail](http://twittercounter.com/pages/twittermail) so you can send a Carbon Copy to [twitter](http://twitter.com), [digg](http://digg.com), [delicious](http://delicious.com) (all of which are good ways to share links) and / or [google bookmarks](http://www.google.com/bookmarks) to be able to choose to have your link into some kind of bookmarking other than private e-mails.

Comment: There is kind of an easier way on iOS, but not on iPad 1, and it needs preparation. 

One side needs an iOS device with a camera, with the app RedLaser (or other QR code reading app). The other side needs an iOS device with this bookmarklet installed in Safari: http://code.google.com/p/qrbookmarklet/ 

Then the person reading the interesting article clicks the bookmark and a QR code of the URL pops up, and the other person scans the QR code in RedLaser which opens Safari with to that page.

Two touches for the person with the article, three for the other, no email.

Comment: @Tessallating I don't consider it easier needing a line of view and pointing to the device in the proper way. And he never said his friend is close by. I might want to share links with my friend in another country. But that's an interesting idea anyway. :P I still find the best way for doing it while nearby would be something like bonjour / bluetooth show devices nearby and send. But it would need to be integrated with the browser and to do it with safari jailbreak is needed, which breaks the "easy" part again.

Answer (score 1):

For compatible iOS devices running iOS 7 and later, the easiest way to share URLs (and various other items) is to use AirDrop, a feature build into iOS.

AirDrop works only on **iPad (4th generation)** and later running iOS 7. The complete list of compatible iOS devices can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirDrop#iOS_requirements_(transfer_between_two_iOS_devices)).

For more details, please go through the Apple Support article, [Use AirDrop on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204144).